# Any way of not displaying white mesh border lines in 3D viewport when texture painting?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm painting a mesh with two materials, but I don't want to paint over the other materials, so I have the "face selection masking for painting" on. 
The problem is that it shows these white mesh lines.
Is there any way to turn that off, so it's easier to see what I'm painting?

I don't remember this being a problem in 2.79

[image]

Comment: Simply turn off overlays in the top right corner over there by the gizmo, and then toggle back when you need to see your selection outline again.

Comment: Ah great! For me it was on the bottom right, but I found it. Thanks Craig!

Answer (score 1):

Turn off overlays by pressing this button, either in the top or bottom right of the 3D Viewport

[image]